# AxWebbrowser Event Handlers not working anymore

Tags: c#, event-handling, axwebbrowser

The event handlers on my program don't work anymore for some reason. This same exact code I've ran several times before.

```
object loc = "http://www.google.com/";
object null_obj_str = "";
System.Object null_obj = 0;

this.axWebBrowser1.Navigate2(ref loc , ref null_obj, ref null_obj, ref null_obj_str, ref null_obj_str);

this.axWebBrowser1.DocumentComplete += new AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.axWebBrowser1_DocumentComplete);

private void axWebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(object sender, AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEvent e)
    {//Do some action}
```

There is not reason why this shouldn't work but that's exactly what's happening. I tried making others events and they don't work either. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I moved from WinXP SP2 to WinXP 3 and my events stopped working also. After digging in the web I discovered I needed to recreate my InterOp DLL's using a program called AXIMP.